# Azure Function with Dependency Injection doesn't create instance of my service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am following this post, and implemented the `Startup` class so that I can inject my services in the constructor, but the service instance is always null and I am getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` when I run the application.

Below is my `Startup` class.

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Backup.Functions.Startup))]
namespace Backup.Functions {
    public class Startup: FunctionsStartup {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton < IBlobService,
            BlobService > ();
        }
    }
}
```

My Function code is as below.

```
public class DeleteDailyBlobs {
    private static IBlobService _blobService;
    public DeleteDailyBlobs(IBlobService blobService) {
        _blobService = blobService;
    } 
    [FunctionName("DeleteDailyBlobs")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0/3 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log) {
        if (_blobService.PerformTasks().GetAwaiter().GetResult()) {
            log.LogInformation(SuccessMessages.FunctionExecutedSuccessfully);
        }
        else {
            log.LogError(ErrorMessages.SomethingBadHappened);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the `_blobService` is always null.

[image]

Comment: why would you inject a blobservice wrapper inside of your function? you are increasing the complexity of your code and decreasing maintainability. do you think you are doing unit tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I was able to find what was the issue, unfortunately I forgot to mark my function `non static`, so all I had to do was to remove the `static` keyword from my Azure Function. After removing that, everything was fine.

```
public void Run([TimerTrigger("0/3 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

As Nkosi was mentioning we should mark the return type of the Function as `Task` and I have written an article about this, and can be found [here](https://sibeeshpassion.com/azure-function-job-to-delete-azure-blobs-from-blob-containers/).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making the function a non static member, you should make the function return a `Task` and await the async function call.

```
public class DeleteDailyBlobs {
    private readonly IBlobService blobService;

    public DeleteDailyBlobs(IBlobService blobService) {
        this.blobService = blobService;
    } 

    [FunctionName("DeleteDailyBlobs")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0/3 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log) {
        if (await blobService.PerformTasks()) {
            log.LogInformation(SuccessMessages.FunctionExecutedSuccessfully);
        }
        else {
            log.LogError(ErrorMessages.SomethingBadHappened);
        }
    }
}
```

And since the dependency is also being added as a singleton, there really is no need to make it a static field as well. The instance will be the same where ever it is injected.

Comment: That is a very good point, and I had already updated my code and written an article about it. The information is been added to the answer.

Comment: What's the reason for needing to await it?